Passing special characters without encoding in HTTPX or Requests
The API that I'm using (wunderground) requires that the date be in the format "2001-01-01 10:32:35", which (they claim) should be URL escaped to "2000-01-01+10%3A32%3A35". Both HTTPX and Requests do this well, except they encode the + to %2B, which the API is not expecting. How do I keep Requests or HTTPX from encoding the +?
Example code:

auth = {
        'ID': station,
        'PASSWORD': stationKey,
        'dateutc': 2024-08-07+19%3A58%3A43,
        'tempf': 65.1,
        'action': "updateraw"
           }

            
r = httpx.get('https://weatherstation.wunderground.com/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php', params=auth)

OR

r = requests.get('https://weatherstation.wunderground.com/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php', params=auth)

print(r.url)


Output:
https://weatherstation.wunderground.com/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php?ID=XXXX&PASSWORD=XXXXX&dateutc=2024-08-07%2B20%253A08%253A41&tempf=65.1&action=updateraw


How about just encoding subsisting with time and then concatenating subsisting with date, "+", and already encoded time?

That example code isn’t syntactically valid, but try without encoding anything. 'dateutc': '2024-08-07+19:58:43',

you need to use quote_plus instead of quote. quote_plus
here is example code
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
date = "2001-01-01 10:32:35"
expected_date =  "2001-01-01+10%3A32%3A35"
result_date = quote_plus(date)
print(result_date == expected_date)
# >>> True

print(result_date)
'2001-01-01+10%3A32%3A35'

